# Python RexExpression - Identfy Standard

Tags: python, regex, standards

I start with regular expression and like to find standards like:

FR ISO 23213:2020 or DIN EN 2323-2

I try this - in sections, so it easier to manage

```
std_prefix = '[EN|DE|FR| ]?[ISO|DIN][EN|DE|FR| ]?'
std_value = '\d{1,5}(?:[-]\d{1,2})?(?:[:]\d{4})'
std = ''.join([std_prefix, std_value])
```

What I get is: 'EN 2323', 'SO 23213'

- I miss DIN on first example
- I miss always the ending :2020 or -2, if there is one, it is options

thanks for some directions to further fine tune.

Comment: FYI You can test your regular expression against your data on websites like regex101.com.

Comment: Try `(?:(?:EN|DE|FR|ISO|DIN)\s*)*\d+[:-]?\d+`  https://regex101.com/r/CRGWhC/1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using character classes (`[...]`) as if they were grouping constructs, `(...)`. To group several alternatives, use non-capturing groups, `(?:...|...)`.

You can try a pattern like

```py
\b(?:(?:EN|DE|FR)\s+(?:ISO|DIN)|(?:ISO|DIN)\s+(?:EN|DE|FR))\s+\d+[-:]\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRA3Jx/2). If you have a specific requirement to match the trailing numbers, feel free to add limiting quantifiers.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?:EN|DE|FR)\s+(?:ISO|DIN)` - `EN`, `DE` or `FR` and then one or more whitespaces and either an `ISO` or `DIN` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:ISO|DIN)\s+(?:EN|DE|FR)` - either an `ISO` or `DIN` substring,  one or more whitespaces and then `EN`, `DE` or `FR`
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[-:]` - a `-` or `:`
- `\d+` - one or more digits.